# Window action without having so select any record

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11, odoo-12

First and for reference, what I call a window action is an action on the top of a tree view.

Example below:

[image]

**Problem:** if I select no record, Odoo tells me that I have to select record.

**Question:** I would like the action to be called even if there is no record selected: Is that possible?

**Example:** the action for instance will start a popup wizard, if a selection of record is done this selection will be preloaded, if no record is selected I will process myself the data preloaded.

Comment: Example of window action:

<act_window name="New Sub menu"
    res_model="product.product"
    src_model="product.product"
    key2="client_action_multi" 
    view_mode="form" target="new" 
    view_type="form"
    id="act_new_sub_menu" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following context in the window action will allow it to be triggered even if no record is selected:

```
context="{'sidebar_without_id':True}"
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of Action menu you can put your own button inside control panel (e.g. beside create,import button)

Comment: Could you please provide an example of xml doing so ?

Comment: You can achieve using qweb xml and javascript like this     <t t-name="BulkDowload.Buttons">
        <button type="button" class='btn btn-secondary o_button_bulk_download'>
            Bulk Download Syllabus
        </button>
    </t>

Comment: This is my point of view, and down/upvote are subjectives. I was unable to understand with your solution 1/ how to put your button in the action menu and 2/ how to make it appear/link to a cerain model (like standard action window behaviour) and 3/ the javascript part seems missing ?